# Upgrading the external graphics card is possible?

Tags: laptop, intel-graphics, amd-graphics-card

I heard that the internal graphics card is soldered on the motherboard so it's hard to replace it; but what about the external one?
I have 2 graphics adapter in my laptop; one is the Intel (internal) and the other is an AMD graphics adapter. Is it possible to change the AMD card?

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise the model number of your laptop, obtained from the serial number plate underneath the laptop. Without that, we cannot advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can not upgrade even the dedicated GPU which you probably mean when you use the expression "external graphics card" because it is almost always soldered to the main board as well. The only difference between integrated and dedicated GPUs is that the integrated GPU is usually part of the CPU chip and much less powerful than the separate dedicated GPU chip which usually also has its own memory. Some modern laptops support thunderbolt, though and you could use that to attach a true desktop external GPU in an enclosure using usually a USB type C cable. So it's basically a box you can connect to your laptop that requires its own power supply and that is typically the only reasonable way to upgrade laptop graphics.

There are also docks for certain laptops that can hold a GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I heard that it's possible to detach the external one easier than the internal one and someone told me he can detach the external one but cannot change the card with another one.

Comment: You can detach an external GPU at any time and usually the GPU inside that external enclosure can also be swapped for a different one.

Comment: I am confused at the begging you said that I cannot upgrade it and now you say it can be detached and change it with another card

Comment: There are different kinds of graphics card. There is an integrated GPU that is directly on the same chip as the CPU. You cannot upgrade that. Many Laptops also have a dedicated GPU, which is also soldered to the to the main board. You also cannot upgrade that. However if you attach a GPU with Thunderbolt to your laptop ("external graphics card" or "eGPU") you can swap or upgrade that.

Comment: So the dedicated card cannot be replaced by anyway? The way of eGPU is expensive and I cannot use this way I thought I can replace the dedicated card with a modern graphics card.

Comment: Theoretically you could desolder and resolder it if the pinout is similar, but that's just not worth it. An external GPU doesn't cost that much more than a normal dedicated gpu though, maybe like 100€ more which isn't that much considering GPUs already cost a few hundred € if you want a worthwhile upgrade.

Comment: Laptops these days is too much expensive that's why I don't have another way than replacing my old card with new one. But i think I will just upgrade the ram :/

Comment: Dependy on what your current laptop is and what you want it to do that it doesn't and on what your budget is.